# backpropagation neural network generate identical outputs for different input

Tags: c#

I've hit a brick wall with backpropagation neural network and I don't know what might be the problem, please help.

In this sample run, I am using 3 layer ann.

1st layer has 10 input neurons
2nd layer has 7 hidden neurons
3rd layer has 2 output neurons

I am using sigmoid activation function for the hidden neuron, and hyper tangent (i.e tanh) activation function for the output neurons.

In this test, i am using learning rate of 0.1, and momentum constant of 0.01 (I have tried other different combination too, and output still have identical problem).

As show below, the training algorithm stop after n iteration, although, the error is still high.

I am using the data sets below to train, and I also used it to test the network after trained.

I trained the network by mapping all ten input into value between 0 and 1. Simply by taking each input and divide by 5000, and if the result is greater than 1, i set it to be 1. For output, I mapped them to -1 and 1, by divide by 100.

As you can see, the output is identical for different inputs.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Your input is most welcome.

Thanks

********sample output******************

T1 is 0 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.01 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.14 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.14 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.14 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.24 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.32 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0.04 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.32 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0.04 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.32 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0.16 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.32 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0.18 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.32 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0.18 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.35 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

T1 is 0.18 and ANN output is 0.0904967273528686
T2 is -0.35 and ANN output is -0.399660970430866

**sample training data****************and test data after trained
1768,1946,2442,4305,7542,6584,2324,1487,1099,975,0,-1
1767,1946,2444,4309,7551,6575,2318,1483,1100,976,0,-14
1764,1942,2441,4212,7555,6565,2311,1480,1097,972,0,-14
1764,1942,2441,4212,7555,6565,2311,1480,1097,972,0,-14
1762,1944,2445,4339,7571,6500,2302,1478,1095,970,0,-24
1762,1944,2445,4339,7571,6500,2302,1478,1095,970,0,-32
1762,1948,2460,4404,7628,6408,2266,1482,1100,973,4,-32
1762,1948,2460,4404,7628,6408,2266,1482,1100,973,4,-32
1742,1909,2381,4186,7375,6882,2432,1533,1163,999,16,-32
1727,1879,2316,4142,7139,7201,2589,1563,1207,1015,18,-32
1712,1859,2288,4232,7051,7275,2658,1570,1236,1038,18,-35
1712,1859,2288,4232,7051,7275,2658,1570,1236,1038,18,-35
1693,1829,2240,4146,6892,7485,2784,1592,1267,1086,18,-37
1693,1829,2240,4146,6892,7485,2784,1592,1267,1086,16,-40
1669,1802,2199,4229,6766,7528,2966,1624,1282,1126,16,-40
1669,1802,2199,4229,6766,7528,2966,1624,1282,1126,16,-40
1669,1802,2199,4229,6766,7528,2966,1624,1282,1126,16,-40
1648,1772,2153,4301,6602,7608,3244,1681,1289,1160,14,-40
1648,1772,2153,4301,6602,7608,3244,1681,1289,1160,4,-40
1648,1772,2153,4301,6602,7608,3244,1681,1289,1160,4,-40
1640,1790,2217,4722,7082,7233,2860,1612,1249,1159,4,-40
1632,1788,2227,5122,7214,7055,2698,1603,1249,1140,4,-40
1632,1788,2227,5122,7214,7055,2698,1603,1249,1140,4,-40
1621,1782,3170,4590,7293,4816,2829,1608,1257,1118,4,-40
1621,1782,3170,4590,7293,4816,2829,1608,1257,1118,4,-40
1616,1780,4302,3004,6751,6844,2860,1606,1262,1121,4,-40
1616,1780,4302,3004,6751,6844,2860,1606,1262,1121,4,-40
1616,1780,4302,3004,6751,6844,2860,1606,1262,1121,4,-40
1592,1025,5023,3609,7446,6739,2852,1602,1265,1125,4,-40
1592,1025,5023,3609,7446,6739,2852,1602,1265,1125,4,-40
1592,1025,5023,3609,7446,6739,2852,1602,1265,1125,4,-40
1604,1779,5664,3645,7522,6605,2863,1595,1264,1124,4,-40
1601,1945,6094,3701,7592,6487,2918,1590,1262,1127,7,-40
1587,3426,5418,3561,7437,6662,3140,1626,1288,1142,7,-40
1587,3426,5418,3561,7437,6662,3140,1626,1288,1142,7,-40
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,7,-40
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,7,-40
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,7,-40
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,7,-40
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,7,-40
2795,7097,2235,3606,7513,6514,3412,1634,1305,1165,7,-40
2795,7097,2235,3606,7513,6514,3412,1634,1305,1165,7,-40
4374,5780,2240,3635,7554,6458,3337,2228,1306,1169,7,-40
4374,5780,2240,3635,7554,6458,3337,2228,1306,1169,7,-40
4374,5780,2240,3635,7554,6458,3337,2228,1306,1169,7,-40
6657,2127,2247,3679,7613,6373,3085,3845,1307,1173,7,-40
5794,1755,2249,3691,7632,6333,2983,5134,1300,1175,9,-40
4045,1735,2208,3576,7510,6527,2932,4549,3576,1188,9,-40
4045,1735,2208,3576,7510,6527,2932,4549,3576,1188,9,-40
4045,1735,2208,3576,7510,6527,2932,4549,3576,1188,9,-40
4045,1735,2208,3576,7510,6527,2932,4549,3576,1188,9,-40
1543,1725,2194,3556,7501,6556,2787,2384,8183,1484,9,-40
1534,1718,2183,3534,7483,6590,2713,2255,6696,3743,9,-40
1529,1709,2171,3508,7461,6636,2673,2143,5150,5561,9,-40
1525,1705,2162,3492,7446,6673,2659,2042,3743,7173,9,-40
1525,1705,2162,3492,7446,6673,2659,2042,3743,7173,9,-40
1524,1704,2160,3487,7443,6677,2660,2023,3561,7348,9,-40
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,9,-40
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,9,-40
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,9,-40
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,9,-40
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,9,-40
1508,1677,2122,3425,7400,6764,2702,1741,1585,1947,9,-40
1508,1677,2122,3425,7400,6764,2702,1741,1585,1947,9,-40
1505,1672,2119,3415,7401,6772,2709,1756,1476,1659,9,-40
1505,1672,2119,3415,7401,6772,2709,1756,1476,1659,9,-40
1505,1672,2119,3415,7401,6772,2709,1756,1476,1659,9,-40
1505,1672,2119,3415,7401,6772,2709,1756,1476,1659,9,-40
1483,1652,2093,3370,7356,6817,2789,1723,1409,1308,9,-40
1477,1648,2085,3357,7348,6837,2830,1704,1418,1267,9,-40
1476,1642,2076,3337,7323,6866,2873,1705,1416,1276,9,-40
1476,1642,2076,3337,7323,6866,2873,1705,1416,1276,9,-40
1476,1642,2076,3337,7323,6866,2873,1705,1416,1276,9,-40
1472,1638,2073,3336,7329,6862,2888,1730,1395,1282,9,-40
1461,1626,2057,3314,7311,6879,2900,1759,1369,1285,9,-40
1461,1626,2056,3314,7310,6880,2902,1764,1370,1284,9,-40
1458,1621,2052,3304,7311,6891,2915,1792,1382,1262,9,-40
1453,1616,2043,3292,7302,6908,2929,1821,1386,1250,9,-40
1444,1609,2034,3275,7285,6931,2952,1846,1416,1259,9,-40
1443,1610,2036,3278,7287,6924,2947,1847,1418,1261,9,-40
1440,1606,2031,3277,7297,6916,2944,1846,1435,1263,9,-40
1432,1597,2017,3248,7265,6954,2971,1858,1469,1272,9,-40
1432,1597,2017,3248,7265,6954,2971,1858,1469,1272,9,-40
1431,1591,2013,3247,7265,6948,2974,1863,1476,1298,9,-40
1431,1591,2013,3247,7265,6948,2974,1863,1476,1298,9,-40
1428,1587,2008,3240,7263,6947,2982,1870,1483,1326,7,-6

---

As for caution, I thought the training data might have too many similar outputs, so i manually altered some of the output to make it more realistic; and the problem of identical output still there.

here is my altered training data sets,

1768,1946,2442,4305,7542,6584,2324,1487,1099,975,-1,-6
1767,1946,2444,4309,7551,6575,2318,1483,1100,976,0,-44
1764,1942,2441,4212,7555,6565,2311,1480,1097,972,1,-54
1764,1942,2441,4212,7555,6565,2311,1480,1097,972,3,-44
1762,1944,2445,4339,7571,6500,2302,1478,1095,970,3,-24
1762,1944,2445,4339,7571,6500,2302,1478,1095,970,-2,-32
1762,1948,2460,4404,7628,6408,2266,1482,1100,973,4,-32
1762,1948,2460,4404,7628,6408,2266,1482,1100,973,4,-32
1742,1909,2381,4186,7375,6882,2432,1533,1163,999,16,-32
1727,1879,2316,4142,7139,7201,2589,1563,1207,1015,18,-32
1712,1859,2288,4232,7051,7275,2658,1570,1236,1038,22,-35
1712,1859,2288,4232,7051,7275,2658,1570,1236,1038,20,-35
1693,1829,2240,4146,6892,7485,2784,1592,1267,1086,30,-37
1693,1829,2240,4146,6892,7485,2784,1592,1267,1086,15,-40
1669,1802,2199,4229,6766,7528,2966,1624,1282,1126,16,-60
1669,1802,2199,4229,6766,7528,2966,1624,1282,1126,17,-50
1669,1802,2199,4229,6766,7528,2966,1624,1282,1126,18,-30
1648,1772,2153,4301,6602,7608,3244,1681,1289,1160,19,-10
1648,1772,2153,4301,6602,7608,3244,1681,1289,1160,3,-80
1648,1772,2153,4301,6602,7608,3244,1681,1289,1160,-3,-90
1640,1790,2217,4722,7082,7233,2860,1612,1249,1159,2,-70
1632,1788,2227,5122,7214,7055,2698,1603,1249,1140,-2,-40
1632,1788,2227,5122,7214,7055,2698,1603,1249,1140,4,-40
1621,1782,3170,4590,7293,4816,2829,1608,1257,1118,-4,-20
1621,1782,3170,4590,7293,4816,2829,1608,1257,1118,6,-40
1616,1780,4302,3004,6751,6844,2860,1606,1262,1121,-6,-10
1616,1780,4302,3004,6751,6844,2860,1606,1262,1121,5,-40
1616,1780,4302,3004,6751,6844,2860,1606,1262,1121,-5,-50
1592,1025,5023,3609,7446,6739,2852,1602,1265,1125,2,-40
1592,1025,5023,3609,7446,6739,2852,1602,1265,1125,-2,-60
1592,1025,5023,3609,7446,6739,2852,1602,1265,1125,1,-70
1604,1779,5664,3645,7522,6605,2863,1595,1264,1124,-1,-80
1601,1945,6094,3701,7592,6487,2918,1590,1262,1127,5,-40
1587,3426,5418,3561,7437,6662,3140,1626,1288,1142,6,-40
1587,3426,5418,3561,7437,6662,3140,1626,1288,1142,7,-60
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,8,-40
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,4,-60
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,3,-40
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,2,-60
1581,5498,4155,3570,7458,6616,3251,1632,1296,1153,1,-40
2795,7097,2235,3606,7513,6514,3412,1634,1305,1165,2,-50
2795,7097,2235,3606,7513,6514,3412,1634,1305,1165,3,-40
4374,5780,2240,3635,7554,6458,3337,2228,1306,1169,4,-80
4374,5780,2240,3635,7554,6458,3337,2228,1306,1169,5,-40
4374,5780,2240,3635,7554,6458,3337,2228,1306,1169,6,-90
6657,2127,2247,3679,7613,6373,3085,3845,1307,1173,-7,-40
5794,1755,2249,3691,7632,6333,2983,5134,1300,1175,-6,-90
4045,1735,2208,3576,7510,6527,2932,4549,3576,1188,-5,-40
4045,1735,2208,3576,7510,6527,2932,4549,3576,1188,-4,-70
4045,1735,2208,3576,7510,6527,2932,4549,3576,1188,-3,-40
4045,1735,2208,3576,7510,6527,2932,4549,3576,1188,-2,-30
1543,1725,2194,3556,7501,6556,2787,2384,8183,1484,-1,-30
1534,1718,2183,3534,7483,6590,2713,2255,6696,3743,0,-40
1529,1709,2171,3508,7461,6636,2673,2143,5150,5561,1,-40
1525,1705,2162,3492,7446,6673,2659,2042,3743,7173,2,-50
1525,1705,2162,3492,7446,6673,2659,2042,3743,7173,3,-40
1524,1704,2160,3487,7443,6677,2660,2023,3561,7348,4,-50
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,5,-40
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,6,-50
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,7,-40
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,8,-40
1521,1701,2155,3478,7434,6702,2662,1919,1940,8149,9,-60
1508,1677,2122,3425,7400,6764,2702,1741,1585,1947,8,-40
1508,1677,2122,3425,7400,6764,2702,1741,1585,1947,7,-70
1505,1672,2119,3415,7401,6772,2709,1756,1476,1659,6,-40
1505,1672,2119,3415,7401,6772,2709,1756,1476,1659,5,-80
1505,1672,2119,3415,7401,6772,2709,1756,1476,1659,4,-40
1505,1672,2119,3415,7401,6772,2709,1756,1476,1659,3,-70
1483,1652,2093,3370,7356,6817,2789,1723,1409,1308,2,-40
1477,1648,2085,3357,7348,6837,2830,1704,1418,1267,1,-70
1476,1642,2076,3337,7323,6866,2873,1705,1416,1276,0,-40
1476,1642,2076,3337,7323,6866,2873,1705,1416,1276,-1,-50
1476,1642,2076,3337,7323,6866,2873,1705,1416,1276,-2,-40
1472,1638,2073,3336,7329,6862,2888,1730,1395,1282,-3,-90
1461,1626,2057,3314,7311,6879,2900,1759,1369,1285,-4,-40
1461,1626,2056,3314,7310,6880,2902,1764,1370,1284,-5,-90
1458,1621,2052,3304,7311,6891,2915,1792,1382,1262,-6,-40
1453,1616,2043,3292,7302,6908,2929,1821,1386,1250,-7,-90
1444,1609,2034,3275,7285,6931,2952,1846,1416,1259,-8,-40
1443,1610,2036,3278,7287,6924,2947,1847,1418,1261,-9,-70
1440,1606,2031,3277,7297,6916,2944,1846,1435,1263,-8,-40
1432,1597,2017,3248,7265,6954,2971,1858,1469,1272,-7,-80
1432,1597,2017,3248,7265,6954,2971,1858,1469,1272,-6,-40
1431,1591,2013,3247,7265,6948,2974,1863,1476,1298,-5,-50
1431,1591,2013,3247,7265,6948,2974,1863,1476,1298,-4,-40
1428,1587,2008,3240,7263,6947,2982,1870,1483,1326,-3,-60

Comment: "Simply by taking each input and divide by 5000, and if the result is greater than 1" <-- additional result?

Comment: sorry, did i missed something?
what I meant was, I mapped all the input into value between 0 and 1.
i divided all value by 5000, and if it greater than 1, i set it equal 1, and the others are equal that values/500; which is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding more layer 2 hidden neurons.

Also you should explain your training algorithm, preferably with example inputs and outputs.

> For output, I mapped them to -1 and 1, by divide by 100.

What did you divide by 100? Why are you using -1 to 1 for the output range instead of 0 to 1?

Comment: As you can see, I have 2 ouputs (these two output could be anywhere between -100 and 100). And, for my network, I am using tanh function for the output neurons. So, because of that, I took my 2 ouputs and divide them by 100; so that would map output to -1 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think more layer 2 hidden neurons did'nt change the result. IMHO add another hidden layer with also 7 neurons.

Comment: are you saying i should add more hidden layer?

Comment: just wondering, what is the possibility for this to solve the problem, you think?

Comment: Hi

I added in an extra layer to the hidden layer, now it is 10-7-7-2, neurons in each layer, respectively, and the output is still identical. Any thought, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're correctly dividing your inputs and the error isn't going down, it's probably an algorithm issue. Backpropagation can get stuck sometimes, you could try Resilient Propagation which scales itself much better and can avoid getting stuck.